# Memory management with C array in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, memory

I have a c style array used in objective c .m file:

```
Gift gifts[3];
```

And Gift is a struct defined as this:

```
typedef struct {
    NSString *name;
    CCSprite *sprite;
}Gift;
```

This is how I use the array

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    gifts[i].name = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reward%d_%@.png", i+1, location] retain];
    gifts[i].sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:gifts[i].name];
    CGPoint pos = [[GameConfigure sharedManager] getCoordinateforKey:@"REWARD_ITEM"];
    gifts[i].sprite.position = ccp(pos.x+i*238, pos.y);
    [rewardLayer addChild:gifts[i].sprite z:1 tag:100+i];
}
```

How do I manage the memory?
 Do I need to free the C array?

Comment: how and where do you declare your "`gifts`" array?

Comment: In the header file:

    Gift gifts[3];

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869883/objective-c-arc-and-passing-c-arrays-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to free the array, as you don't allocate it.

Are you sure that `spriteWithSpriteFrameName` doesn't return an `autoreleased` object (its naming convention suggests it does)?

Comment: spriteWithSpriteFrameName returns an autorelease object. Does this matter?

Comment: @DragonDoingPragramming Yes, it matters - just as you have done with the `NSString`, you need to `retain` it.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to free C array , but you should manage the Object in the C array

in your code

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {

    //retain is good, but if you don't release it at the end ,  it leaks!!!!
    gifts[i].name = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reward%d_%@.png", i+1, location] retain];

    //here is not a good idea, why you don't retian here?  it will be autorelease 
    gifts[i].sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:gifts[i].name];

    CGPoint pos = [[GameConfigure sharedManager] getCoordinateforKey:@"REWARD_ITEM"];
    gifts[i].sprite.position = ccp(pos.x+i*238, pos.y);
    [rewardLayer addChild:gifts[i].sprite z:1 tag:100+i];
}
```

you'd better create a NSObject instead of the struct GIFT

use Property of the member

```
@interface GIFT : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    CCSprite *sprite;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *sprite;

@end
```

and use NSArray instead of C Array

```
NSArray *gifts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [[[GIFT alloc] init] autorelease],
                                         [[[GIFT alloc] init] autorelease],
                                         [[[GIFT alloc] init] autorelease],
                                         nil];
```

but if you still want to use C array,  try to manage the reference count in the struct of your GIFT

Comment: @interface GIFT : NSObject { NSString *name; CCSprite *sprite; }

I have never seen this kind of implementation, can thou explain a bit?

Comment: eeee...,  what means you have never seen?  it's the definition of a Object in Objective-C just like NSString and CCSprite and etc..

Comment: Hmm... Yeap :) I could not recognize it, haha

Comment: check this, it's so basic. :)  http://nicolaslarrea.blogspot.com/2011/05/creating-custom-object.html